# UnauthorizedAccessException when creating an excel file

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, exception

This code worked just fine on my windows 7 machine, but now on Windows 8 it crashes on the `System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Movie Database.xls");` line

```
Movie_DataGrid.SelectAllCells();
Movie_DataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.ExcludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, Movie_DataGrid);
String resultat = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
FileStream xls = null;
try
{
    try
    {
        xls = new FileStream(@"C:\Movie Database.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        IsProcessOpen("EXCEL");
        xls = new FileStream(@"C:\Movie Database.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException )
{
    MessageBox.Show("File was not found. Creating File");
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Movie Database.xls");
    file.WriteLine(result.Replace(',', ' '));
    file.Close();
}
finally
{
    if (xls != null)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(xls);
        file.WriteLine(result.Replace(',', ' '));
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

I do not have a file called Movie Database.xls created thus it should create the file and write the data to it. I dont know whether it is windows 8 or the fact that i have excel 2013 thats preventing me from having access. Any suggestions as to the exception. Again I used the code on a windows 7 box with excel 2010 just fine so i know it works.

Comment: Is your user granted to write on `c:\`?

Comment: I would ask the same question as @FrancoisB. What happens if you change the path to your documents folder or somewhere that you know you have permissions to.